Create or update an Event with Microsoft Graph-API without sending out an invitation
As part of a migration of calendar data to microsoft exchange, events are created or updated via the graph api. The problem is that all attendees are notified each time.
I tried to search for an answer, but I could not find anything. Several people have asked this question over the last few years, but it seems that no answers have been found so far. It would have been simple if there was a parameter (e.g. disableNotifications: true) that would prevent the sending of invitations, but I have not found anything in the documentation.
One idea was to create an event without attendees and to add them later, but obviously after the list of attendees has been updated via graphapi, invitations are send out. Another idea/workaround was to create a rule in outlook to move these invitation e-mails into the trash folder, but this isn't a feasable solution, since you need permissions from everyone and the invitations do still exist in the trash folder.

Is there an official way to disable invitations being sent out, when creating or updating an event?
If not, does anyone know a workaround / trick / hack how to prevent sending out invitations after creating or updating an event?


You may create a mail flow rule (transport rule) on Exchange Server which blocks meeting request invitation messages from all or specific mailboxes, and activate this during migration times only.
The link below bypasses notification process and writes the event directly to calendar.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/security-and-compliance/mail-flow-rules/use-rules-to-add-meetings#use-the-exchange-admin-center-to-create-direct-to-calendar-mail-flow-rules
